# How can I remove Endermen from the game?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I hate Endermen. They tear apart my beautiful buildings, force me to keep all my rooms below 3 blocks high, make terrible screeching noises, and as far as I'm concerned can all go back to The End and stay there.

But I'm stuck with them...unless there exists a mod out there that can remove Endermen.

So my basic question here is - is there a way to remove specific mobs from the game?

I am not asking for a way to remove ALL mobs from the game (peaceful does that just fine, thank you) or a way to not get hurt by mobs, I am specifically asking for a way to outright remove a mob from the game.  I am okay with every single other type of mob, but Endermen just...no.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Minecraft yet, but can't you build an automated turret to keep your "home" safe? If someone built an entire CPU (or at least parts of it), a simple automated turret, shouldn't be all that difficult! :)

Comment: @Domi That'd keep me safe from ordinary mobs, but Endermen can teleport directly into your home, or onto your roof where they can then remove a top block and drop in uninvited.  An arrow trap really doesn't offer any protection from this.

Comment: @Domi also aren't enderman immune to projectiles

Comment: btw, if you make your floor bottom half slabs, mobs wont spawn on it. so you can make rooms higher than 3 blocks. (althogh i am not entirely sure it is bottom half slabs :/)

Comment: @HelloWorld That only takes care of Endermen spawning inside my home, not Endermen teleporting in.

Comment: Well, Read this post if you have time:  http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/955141-disable-remove-enderman-endermen/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a built-in server command to stop the picking-up blocks portion.
Type this in the server window, if you're running the server:

```
gamerule mobGriefing false
```

Or type this in the game chat window, if you're an op (or single-player, I believe):

```
/gamerule mobGriefing false
```

This will also stop Creeper explosions from damaging blocks.

However, this will not remove Enderman, so there is still the noise issue.

Source:
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Server_commands

Comment: It also won't stop them from teleporting in, which is an even bigger issue than the noise or block-grabbing.  But it's still useful.  Especially for building.

Comment: -1; `mobGriefing true` enables mobGriefing. It should be `mobGriefing false`. I attempted to edit this answer to correct it, but for some reason [the reviewers decided to reject my edit](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/78421).

Comment: @Bryan Because that should be a comment (like what you just did), not an edit, which are for grammatical errors and the like, not changing the meaning of a post.

Comment: @Doorknob I raised the issue on meta earlier. I was in the mindset of correcting a typo rather than changing the meaning, but I fully accept the reason for rejecting the edit.

Comment: Rejecting this sort of edit makes no sense at all to me. If the command is wrong, it probably was a simple mistake. Why force people to trip over the wrong command? :( I'd like to understand the reasoning here, but I can't see it.

Comment: @aikeru: see the meta post, it's explained there.

Comment: Whoops, thanks for the correction.  It's been a while seen I've played around with my server.  Although if I think about it, false makes a lot more sense.

Comment: We do NOT edit answers to make them correct.  That's what downvotes are for.  Editing is for *clarity*.  If the answer is wrong, **downvote** it, not correct it.  Leave it to the answerer themselves to correct their answers.

Comment: That is a terrible practice.  If the answerer corrects it, your downvote still applies and it's up to the downvoter to go back and un-downvote, which might not ever happen.

Comment: @JoshDM There's a reason upvotes weigh so much more heavily than downvotes.  A single upvote can wipe out *five* downvotes.

Comment: @Frank - only from a reputation standpoint; not from an "is this a valid answer that just needs a quick one-word edit" standpoint.

Comment: @JoshDM An answer is an answer.  If it's not correct, it'll get buried in downvotes, and eventually deleted.  Yes, Arqade allows collaborative edits, but it is not our place to change the intent of the answer.  If it's wrong, downvote.  If it's low quality, edit it.  Or downvote.  We don't downvote nearly enough here.

Comment: Answer edited, downvote is now an upvote :)

Comment: @Bryan - I suspect you're the only one who cared enough to come back.

Comment: What you are showing everyone *here* is that you are unwilling to let others fix their mistakes. You have been very hypocritical as you have made several mistakes in your life. You have shown no logic or common sense as not fixing the mistake would confuse some of the readers and it would take a long time till this post gets deleted. The answer itself is right but there was an typo in it. Lets say that Bryan spelled "Enderman" wrong. That's part of the answer and relates to the problem right? So would you let him fix this mistake. What if he said it stops Ender Dragons from destroying blocks?

Comment: If he did say that, would you have let him fix his mistake? This mistake makes the answer not relevant. Also, from a person who accepts others view: The answer (the wrong one before) is actually right but to a different question. So the answer it self is always right. But is only wrong to whoever thinks it is wrong, whoever has a negative view of others, and or whoever is judgmental. Just let others fix their mistakes, stopping them has just wasted a lot of others time as they might have entered the wrong command or have replied to this post. None of this would happen if the mistake was fixed.

Comment: There's issues with changing the mobGriefing gamerule to true, this will cause villager breeders to stop working, I run a server and I've installed the Anti-Enderman Griefing datapack from https://vanillatweaks.net so that they don't wreck our custom terrain

Answer (score 17):

Yes. There are mods to [completely remove Endermen](http://www.planetminecraft.com/mod/no-more-enders/) and others that [disable their ability to pick up blocks](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/631622-endermen-dont-pick-up-blocks-mod/).

Comment: Well that was quick. :)

Comment: Google helps :)

Comment: Can't search for most gaming-related things at work sadly. But now I can definitely use these once I get home.

Comment: But you can post on gaming.stackexchange? :P

Comment: My works the exactly same, can't get on the majority of websites, can't download zip files (which is annoying being a web developer you'd have thought IT would trust us), but I can get on all ctackexchage sites :P.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use (in the newest Minecraft snapshots) this command blocks.

You make a clock and place a command block to the side of the redstone, with this command.

```
/kill @e[type=Enderman]
```

He kills every Enderman in the game.

Comment: An even cleaner version of this would be `/tp @e[type=Enderman] ~ -1 ~`, which would teleport endermen out of the world.

Comment: Wouldn't they still be able to spawn though?

Comment: They would still *technically* spawn, but every time the command block is activated, they would instantly die/be teleported out of the world. I doubt you'd ever see them, and if you did, it would only be for a split second. Also, this would only work if the chunk containing the command block is loaded, although it is probably the best way to do it without the use of mods.

Comment: if you place the command block in spawn chunk, it should always be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Endermen wreck stuff, and can be the bane of existence for modellers...and everyone else. More games need to allow users to customize the game to their liking, so users can have fun how they want to. So, very good answers above, that 100% answer the question of how to remove specific mobs, especially Endermen, from the game.

But, what about solutions for people that want to play vanilla?  I don't think there is a way to do it without making things look really ugly, but a lava-moat around a building with 2 block high ceilings and lava-covered roof might just do the trick.

According to the minecraft wiki on defense against Endermen,
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Endermen#Defense
, water also does the trick, and would be slightly more visually appealing, methinks.

How about heavily forested areas?  Fire hazards, but do Endermen walk on leaves?

Also, while well lit areas will not be 100% effective, they will deter spawning a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try MC Combat Training Mod. See https://sites.google.com/site/mccombattraining/
The Witch and Enderman are disabled by default,
You can enable or disable it with a command.
/mof Enderman will disable it.