# How can I completely disable a particular vanilla mob in Minecraft 1.7.10?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I want to play Minecraft with a friend who has a debilitating fear of spiders. I would like a way to ensure that spiders, of any variety, will never appear in the game. Ever. Anywhere. Including appearing in spawners. I am playing in 1.7.10 for mod compatibility. Is this even possible?

I am willing to use mods, but I have not had the best luck with the mob spawn controlling mods. I have the 1.7.10 version of Mob Spawn Controls, but (at least using the in-game UI), it seems to have a minimum of 1, not 0, possibly because I am not understanding its system. It also doesn't appear to affect spawners. Just Another Spawner baffles me completely, so I am worried I would miss something and spiders would appear. Again, no control over spawners that I know of.

Editing the Minecraft jar file directly to replace the model, animation, and sounds with those from another mob without changing the effects is not out of the question, as it is the imagery that is a problem, not the game effects. I could make little ninjas based on the little zombie; that would fit with the behavior reasonably well. I am just not sure how involved the edits would have to be, and a bit concerned about breaking compatibility with unmodified versions (since we want to play with friends).

Comment: Very well-written question you've posted here. Welcome to Arqade!

Comment: Are command blocks in the question? You can setup a clock that will instantly teleport all spiders to the void as soon as they spawn. This will kill the spiders but won't display them at all, even the death animation. the only problem is the spawners you mentioned.

Comment: @user3878893 that won't work. You'd need the `@e` selector which was only introduced in 1.8.

Comment: If the spider textures are the only problem, not the mobs themselves, you could get a copy of the default texture pack and edit the spider and cave spider textures to something else.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/163756/how-can-i-remove-endermen-from-the-game/163758#163758

Answer (score 2):

I actually found a solution that works for me, specifically. The More Commands mod includes the /ignorespawn command, which prevents mobs from ever spawning. They will still appear in spawners, but only the little model shows; they don't actually spawn. The model spins, and periodically the spawner flashes, but no spiders.  I still need to ask my friend, but I don't think that will be a problem; he will probably just be very motivated to break those spawners. :-)

http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/2382164-more-commands-v2-4-adds-100-commands-to-the-chat

Not quite as good as removing them entirely, but I think it will work, and it is an easy way to avoid actually encountering mobs you don't want to see. You can add the command in the configuration, and it will be active on all world's by default.

Answer (score -4):

You can connect a redstone clock to a command block that has this command:

**/kill @e[type=Spider]** As for the spawners, you can go to MCEdit, press "select all" then use the Fill and Replace tool to replace all the spider spawners in the world with air.

I hope this helped!

Comment: The `@e` selector was not introduced until 1.8.

Comment: The person asking is currently playing on 1.7.10 and the @e selector was added in 1.8.